# Is the Samsung 850 Evo compatible with Dell Latitude E6400?

Tags: compatibility, dell-latitude

Is the Samsung 850 Evo SSD compatible with Dell Latitude E6400 notebook?

Comment: The 840 is so more than likely the 850 is...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onbuAxXptOs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 850 EVO SSD in 2.5 inch form factor is [6.8 mm in height](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/ssd850evo/specifications.html), so as long as the height available for the new drive is sufficient then it will fit. There *will* be enough height for it.

The old drive might be 9.5 mm in height, but as long as you secure the new drive correctly with the screws then it will not be loose.

Electrically and electronically it will work. You just need to make sure that you do not accidentally order an M.2 form factor version.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually any SSD should work, as long as you have the installation media to reinstall Windows?